# `sscanf` for `%%` does not work as expected

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer, scanf

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// [Example 5 from C17; Page 238](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)

int main(void) {
  int n = 0;
  int i = 0;

  n = sscanf("foo %bar 42", "foo%%bar%d", &i);

  printf("n = %d\ni = %d\n", n, i);

  return 0;
}
```

According to the C17 Standard, it should print

```
n = 1
i = 42
```

However, on my platform it prints

```
n = 0
i = 0
```

`gcc -v` on my platform gives:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/R/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/inst_gcc-12.1.0/share/gcc --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --with-pkgversion='MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders' --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --enable-threads=posix --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-serial-configure --disable-bootstrap --enable-host-shared --enable-plugin --disable-default-ssp --disable-rpath --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-stabs --disable-symvers --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++,jit --disable-gold --disable-nls --disable-stage1-checking --disable-win32-registry --disable-multilib --enable-ld --enable-libquadmath --enable-libada --enable-libssp --enable-libstdcxx --enable-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-graphite --enable-mingw-wildcard --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-mpc=/e/Prog/wi
nlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-mpfr=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-gmp=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/cu
stombuilt --with-isl=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-install-libiberty --enable
-__cxa_atexit --without-included-gettext --with-diagnostics-color=auto --enable-clocale=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-
zlib --with-build-sysroot=/R/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/gcc-12.1.0/build_mingw/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-I/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/cust
ombuilt/include/libdl-win32 -D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS' CXXFLAGS=-D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS LDFLAGS='-Wl,--disable-nxcompat -Wl,--disable-high-entropy-va -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.1.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)
```

**ADDED:**
I tried another platform, it does print

```
n = 1
i = 42
```

On this platform, `gcc -v` shows:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl
=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c
++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linu
ithout-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
ithout-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
ithout-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
ithout-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

So it seems that this is a bug of the compiler on the first platform?

Comment: Next time please also copy the console output as text instead of posting an image. Thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude per man page, "most conversions skip white space", and as the snippet indicates the example comes straight from the spec. An anecdotally it works perfectly fine in clang 14.

Comment: After some *very* quick research, I'd argue that it's a bug in Windows and the Microsoft VC++ CRT implementation that is used by MinGW. Which is not that unheard of, unfortunately.

Comment: @Masklinn It also works on my Linux platform.

Comment: Trying out various compilers in godbolt it also seems like a bug in either mingw or the windows crt to me, but godbolt doesn't support visual c++ as a compiler so it's not possible to see if *that* works correctly on its own.

Comment: @Masklinn You're correct. `%%` is a "normal" conversion sequence, and *not* listed as one that doesn't skip whitespace.

Comment: This first example definitely appears to demonstrate a non-conformity in the MS C runtime library.  The second (new) one I learned about today!

Comment: I wonder why `%%` wasn't defined to be one of the exceptions that do not consume initial whitespace? I think it would make more sense if it was one of the exceptions, otherwise there is no way to match and consume a `%` without also consuming initial whitespace. I guess the standard behavior is for historical reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of your first platform does not conform to the C standard. C 2018 7.21.6.2 7 and 8 say:

> A directive that is a conversion specification defines a set of matching input sequences, as described below for each specifier. A conversion specification is executed in the following steps:
>
> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.

`%%` is a conversion specification (because 7.21.6.2 3 says the format string is composed of directives which are one or more white-space characters, an ordinary multibyte character, or a conversion specification, and that each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`) and does not include `[`, `c`, or `n`, so input white-space characters before it should be skipped.

Equivalent language appears in versions of the standard going back to 1990.

You should test compiling with `-std=c17` just in case there is some issue with default compilations using the C library in a non-conforming mode. (I do not think that is likely, but it is theoretically possible.)

Comment: Moreover, the spec explicitly lists `%` among the conversion specifiers that may appear in a conversion specification.  There's no ambiguity in the spec at all about `%%` being a conversion specification (just unfortunately similar distinct terms "conversion specification" and "conversion specifier").

Answer (score 2):

7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function (which shares definition with `sscanf` except for where the input comes from part):

> 8. Input white-space characters <s>(as specified by the function)</s> are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.

Since your specification does *not* include one of the specifiers included in the exception list, `sscanf` *should* skip the whitespaces. My conclusion is that the implementation of `sscanf` on your platform is wrong.